# How to make pagination by $category->companies in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I listed my category companies and i want to paginate by them. How can i do it?

This is my view:

```
@foreach ($category->companies as $singleCompany)
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    <!-- product card -->

    <div class="product-item bg-light">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"><a href="{{ url('/company/' . $singleCompany->id) }}">{{$singleCompany->name}}</a></h4>
                @foreach ($singleCompany->categories as $singleCategories)
                    <ul class="list-inline product-meta">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>{{ $singleCategories->name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

My controller looks like this:

```
    $companies = Company::filterByRequest($request)->paginate(9);
    $category = Category::find($id);
```

My category schema:

```
        if(! Schema::hasTable('categories')) {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('icon')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->index(['deleted_at']);
        });
```

My company schema:

```
        if(! Schema::hasTable('companies')) {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('city_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('categories')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('logo')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->index(['deleted_at']);
        });
    }
```

Pivot table for company_category

```
if(! Schema::hasTable('category_company')) {
        Schema::create('category_company', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id', 'fk_p_91029_91033_company__5a12afe2d2772')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('company_id', 'fk_p_91033_91029_category_5a12afe2d27f0')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
```

Can i use somehow $category->companies to paginate my companies? Thank you for help.

[image]

Comment: I would like to clarify. You wanted to paginate companies under the chosen category right? If so, can you edit you question and put the table schema of table company and category. thanks

Comment: is the column `$table->string('categories')->nullable();` a foreign key? what is the relation of companies and categories table?

Comment: it have extra pivot table. when filling form must add category. i will add it too

Comment: public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_company')->withTrashed();

Comment: public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'category_company')->withTrashed();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't know if `$category->companies` would be possible in this case.

You might want to try this code.

```
$companies = Company::leftJoin('category_company', 'companies.id', 
                                '=', 'category_company.company_id')
                        ->where('category_id', $id)
                        ->paginate(9);
```

- This code will left join the table companies and category_company.
- It will also be able to get the companies that has the chosen category id.
- The result is also ready for pagination in your blade.

Comment: yes you are right! Just fix Object from Companies to Company

Comment: one problem it shows 10 objects for example. but it should show just 9

Comment: the data results in the object `$companies` will be based on the no. of pagination.

Comment: if it solves your problem you can mark your question as answered. Thanks!

Comment: I will, but firstly i want make sure its really correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161194/discussion-between-miggy-and-darius).

Answer (score 0):

`$category->companies` will return an Eloquent collection with all companies and not an instance of `LengthAwarePaginator`.

`$companies` will return an instance of `LengthAwarePaginator`, so iterate over it.

In comments, you've said you want to load companies of specified category. If you've defined the `belongsToMany()` relationship already, use `whereHas()` to filter by category:

```
$companies = Company::filterByRequest($request)
    ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use($categoryId) {
        $q->where('id', $categoryId);
    })
    ->paginate(9);
```

Then display companies:

```
@foreach ($companies as $singleCompany)
    {{ $singleCompany->name }}
@endforeach
```

And add pagination links:

```
{{ $companies->render() }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Comment: But I need render by selected category companies. Thats why i have $category = Category::find($id); After selecting category I need to show selected category companies. Thats why it is $category->companies as $singleCompany

Answer (score 0):

If you want pagination for category you have to use paginate() for category.

Try changing your get category query by this

```
$category = Category::where('unique_id', $id)->paginate(9);
```

Then you can use `{{ $category->render() }}` where you need pagination

Comment: In which column you need to find that $id?